# How to define default size of image upload in Magento?

Tags: magento, resize

When i upload is creating a 600x800 image folder, and i want to use the default 600x600 size.
I tryed in:

```
System> Catalog> Product Image
```

In Base Image Width, but not work.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score 0):

You need to check your app/design/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml the dimension are many times hard coded as per the tempalte. You will find big Image X & Y pixels which needs to be changed as per your requirement. Find your correct file and try making the changes.